# SSIS Merge component performing a UNION instead of merging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a package to combine data from multiple databases. I'm trying to bring together two data sets so they can be written to a single table.

There's a common `SSIS_ID (DT_I4)` used to match rows and the other columns I want to bring in to the same data set are also `DT_I4`.

Here's the section of the flow where the problem is; as you can see the data from both paths is sorted on `SSIS_ID` before entering the Merge:

[image: SSIS data flow]

And here is the configuration of the Merge component. The intention is to put the `CRO_CompanyID` and `Sponsor_CompanyID` for the same `SSIS_ID` in to a single row:

[image: Merge configuration]

However the output of the merge is acting like a `UNION`; there are 1,532 rows entering from the left and 4,303 from the right resulting in 5,835 rows at the output.

A data viewer on the output shows the problem:

[image]

I can get around this problem by processing the data in a different way but it's really bugging me that I can't get this to work.

Any suggestions as to what I have done wrong or not done to be able to combine the data in this way?

*I'm using SSIS for SQL Server 2008 but there wasn't a tag for that version.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the wrong transformation.

"The Merge transformation is similar to the Union All transformations." -[MSDN Merge Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141703%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

You can use the [Merge Join transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141775.aspx) and specify your join type, then select the input column used for each output.

[image]

Then you can get your desired output:
[image]

If your source(s) is an RDBMS system it's better to sort with an `ORDER BY` as opposed to using a Sort task, since it is a blocking component and the DB can likely perform the sort faster.

Comment: I tried changing the 'Merge' for a 'Merge Join' but I was not able to get the result set I wanted. So I left the 'Merge' in place and worked around it. Having said that, your answer is correct in that a 'Merge' is a 'UNION' task, so really I should've approached the problem in a different way. I'm aware the sort is blocking but the data had to be sorted by a different field earlier in the flow, and as I only have a few thousand rows it's not a problem.

Comment: Sounds good glad you got it worked out. I always mention the sort, just in case.